# Issues building dOxygen with cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, doxygen, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to compile the source files for dOxygen verseion 1.8.13 using cmake. I have all the correct libraries and compilers properly downloaded and set up, but it still returns errors for me. I downloaded the tar.gz package from the dOxygen website and unpacked them with tar.

I then ran this command to finish compiling (as it says to do on the website):

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" ..
```

Which gives me the following printout:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBISON.cmake:102 (message):
Command "C:/Users/Barr/Documents/bison-2.4.1-bin/bin/bison.exe --version"
failed with output:

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:69 (find_package)


-- Found BISON: C:/Users/Barr/Documents/bison-2.4.1-bin/bin/bison.exe
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Looking for iconv_open
-- Looking for iconv_open - not found
-- Performing Test ICONV_COMPILES
-- Performing Test ICONV_COMPILES - Success
-- Found ICONV: C:/tools/doxygen-1.8.13/winbuild/iconv.lib
-- One (and only one) of the ICONV_ACCEPTS_... tests must pass
-- Performing Test ICONV_ACCEPTS_NONCONST_INPUT
-- Performing Test ICONV_ACCEPTS_NONCONST_INPUT - Failed
-- Performing Test ICONV_ACCEPTS_CONST_INPUT
-- Performing Test ICONV_ACCEPTS_CONST_INPUT - Success
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I removed some of the info returned at the beginning of the command since all they did was indicate things that had been done successfully. Is there something I may be missing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Given that this is a first question asked by a new user it may help to point out what specifically doesn't fit in with questions for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Louis I believe they can easily figure out themselves with the given infomration.

Comment: According to the output, CMake thinks your bison executable is broken. Try to run `C:/Users/Barr/Documents/bison-2.4.1-bin/bin/bison.exe --version` in the terminal.

Comment: Thank you Tsyvarev, that fixed the issue! Also, Louis Langholtz, why do you say my question doesn't fit in Stack Overflow? Where should I be asking questions like this? I have some more questions and issues relating to dOxygen and I'd like to know where I should ask them.

Comment: For me, the question looks OK. However, checking things which are **directly** noted in the error log is what you could do *before the asking*. Also, as you have found the solution by yourself, you may write an **answer** to the question. This will help futher readers, who get same or similar error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had an out of date version of bison.exe. Updating to a newer version allowed the build to complete succesfully.